# Unable to find the client ID in aws iot for data retrieval in my Flutter app. Please guide

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, iot, nodemcu

I have uploaded data using arduino on AWS IOT , I want to retrieve data to my flutter app, but unable to find client ID in AWS iot. Help me to find client ID in Aws IOT

I am trying to retrieve data from AWS IoT